# Shell script to switch first and last names and sort records

Tags: scripts, sed

I am newbie and I am stuck on this problem.

I need to switch the first name and last name. There are no spaces between the first name and last name just a comma.

I need to change this:

```
firstName,lastName         25
```

To this:

```
lastName,firstName         25
```

What I have tried:

```bash
sed -E 's/^(.*),(.*)$/\2, \1/' fileName
```

But my result was this:

```
lastName      25, firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "firstName,lastName         25" | sed -E 's/^(.*),([^ ]*)$/\2,\1/'
```

Output:

```
lastName,firstName         25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```bash
sed -E -e 's/^([0-9]{1,2}), ([[:alpha:] ]+) ([[:alpha:] ]+),/\1 \3 \2,/;' filename
```